# Why the android studio emulator wont work?

Tags: android, api, emulation, haxm

Since yesterday the android studio device emulator wont work any more.

Didnt change anything of the project and before everything worked very well.
Tried to change the compile and target version the build versions and also some different api but it wont work.
I deinstalled android studio and also deinstall and install all sdk tools but nothing worked so far. Tried to change the adv settings and also looked up in the internet but didnt find a solution. There isnt any errors or something that looks suspicious in the logs and dont know how to solve it and run it.

The display stay white when i start the application only the status bar is colored with the color i chosed.

Run:

```
Connected to process 6174 on device 'Pixel_4_XL_API_30 [emulator-5554]'.
Capturing and displaying logcat messages from application. This behavior can be disabled in the "Logcat output" section of the "Debugger" settings page.
I/.n.newnightsta: Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
I/.n.newnightsta: Unquickening 12 vdex files!
W/.n.newnightsta: Unexpected CPU variant for X86 using defaults: x86
D/ApplicationLoaders: Returning zygote-cached class loader: /system/framework/android.test.base.jar
I/.n.newnightsta: The ClassLoaderContext is a special shared library.
D/NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
D/NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
D/libEGL: loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libEGL_emulation.so
D/libEGL: loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_emulation.so
D/libEGL: loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv2_emulation.so
W/.n.newnightsta: Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/View;->computeFitSystemWindows(Landroid/graphics/Rect;Landroid/graphics/Rect;)Z (greylist, reflection, allowed)
    Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/ViewGroup;->makeOptionalFitsSystemWindows()V (greylist, reflection, allowed)
D/HostConnection: HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xed360840, tid 6203
D/HostConnection: HostComposition ext ANDROID_EMU_CHECKSUM_HELPER_v1 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v2 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v3 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v4 ANDROID_EMU_dma_v1 ANDROID_EMU_direct_mem ANDROID_EMU_host_composition_v1 ANDROID_EMU_host_composition_v2 ANDROID_EMU_vulkan ANDROID_EMU_deferred_vulkan_commands ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_null_optional_strings ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_create_resources_with_requirements ANDROID_EMU_YUV_Cache ANDROID_EMU_async_unmap_buffer ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_ignored_handles ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_free_memory_sync ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_shader_float16_int8 ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_async_queue_submit GL_OES_EGL_image_external_essl3 GL_OES_vertex_array_object GL_KHR_texture_compression_astc_ldr ANDROID_EMU_host_side_tracing ANDROID_EMU_async_frame_commands ANDROID_EMU_gles_max_version_3_0 
W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to choose config with EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED, retrying without...
D/EGL_emulation: eglCreateContext: 0xed360990: maj 3 min 0 rcv 3
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xed360990: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xed5ad0f0) (first time)
I/Gralloc4: mapper 4.x is not supported
D/HostConnection: createUnique: call
    HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xed361790, tid 6203
D/goldfish-address-space: allocate: Ask for block of size 0x100
D/goldfish-address-space: allocate: ioctl allocate returned offset 0x3f806f000 size 0x2000
D/HostConnection: HostComposition ext ANDROID_EMU_CHECKSUM_HELPER_v1 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v2 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v3 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v4 ANDROID_EMU_dma_v1 ANDROID_EMU_direct_mem ANDROID_EMU_host_composition_v1 ANDROID_EMU_host_composition_v2 ANDROID_EMU_vulkan ANDROID_EMU_deferred_vulkan_commands ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_null_optional_strings ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_create_resources_with_requirements ANDROID_EMU_YUV_Cache ANDROID_EMU_async_unmap_buffer ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_ignored_handles ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_free_memory_sync ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_shader_float16_int8 ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_async_queue_submit GL_OES_EGL_image_external_essl3 GL_OES_vertex_array_object GL_KHR_texture_compression_astc_ldr ANDROID_EMU_host_side_tracing ANDROID_EMU_async_frame_commands ANDROID_EMU_gles_max_version_3_0 
I/.n.newnightsta: Waiting for a blocking GC ProfileSaver
I/.n.newnightsta: WaitForGcToComplete blocked ProfileSaver on RunEmptyCheckpoint for 5.974ms
```

Logcat:

```
 021-01-26 14:10:33.265 1283-2283/com.google.android.gms E/angh: Phenotype API error. Event # caox@6d0132fb, EventCode: 12 [CONTEXT service_id=51 ]
    anfl: 29503
        at angn.b(:com.google.android.gms@201817022@20.18.17 (040700-311416286):25)
        at angh.a(:com.google.android.gms@201817022@20.18.17 (040700-311416286):90)
        at angh.a(:com.google.android.gms@201817022@20.18.17 (040700-311416286):77)
        at zus.run(:com.google.android.gms@201817022@20.18.17 (040700-311416286):10)
        at blot.run(:com.google.android.gms@201817022@20.18.17 (040700-311416286):2)
        at sji.b(:com.google.android.gms@201817022@20.18.17 (040700-311416286):12)
        at sji.run(:com.google.android.gms@201817022@20.18.17 (040700-311416286):7)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at spj.run(:com.google.android.gms@201817022@20.18.17 (040700-311416286):0)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)
2021-01-26 14:10:33.267 1283-2283/com.google.android.gms E/AsyncOperation: serviceID=51, operation=GetCommittedConfigurationOperationCall
    OperationException[Status{statusCode=unknown status code: 29503, resolution=null}]
        at angh.a(:com.google.android.gms@201817022@20.18.17 (040700-311416286):92)
        at angh.a(:com.google.android.gms@201817022@20.18.17 (040700-311416286):77)
        at zus.run(:com.google.android.gms@201817022@20.18.17 (040700-311416286):10)
        at blot.run(:com.google.android.gms@201817022@20.18.17 (040700-311416286):2)
        at sji.b(:com.google.android.gms@201817022@20.18.17 (040700-311416286):12)
        at sji.run(:com.google.android.gms@201817022@20.18.17 (040700-311416286):7)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at spj.run(:com.google.android.gms@201817022@20.18.17 (040700-311416286):0)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)
2021-01-26 14:10:33.271 1283-2957/com.google.android.gms E/NetRec: [187] akiy.a: Could not retrieve server token for package com.google.android.apps.gcs
    java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: rey: 29503: 
        at auct.b(:com.google.android.gms@201817022@20.18.17 (040700-311416286):5)
        at auct.a(:com.google.android.gms@201817022@20.18.17 (040700-311416286):23)
        at akiy.a(:com.google.android.gms@201817022@20.18.17 (040700-311416286):1)
        at akiy.a(:com.google.android.gms@201817022@20.18.17 (040700-311416286):4)
        at akix.getHeaders(:com.google.android.gms@201817022@20.18.17 (040700-311416286):2)
        at com.android.volley.toolbox.HttpClientStack.performRequest(:com.google.android.gms@201817022@20.18.17 (040700-311416286):18)
        at sdq.performRequest(:com.google.android.gms@201817022@20.18.17 (040700-311416286):1)
        at bqg.executeRequest(:com.google.android.gms@201817022@20.18.17 (040700-311416286):1)
        at com.android.volley.toolbox.BasicNetwork.performRequest(:com.google.android.gms@201817022@20.18.17 (040700-311416286):9)
        at sdr.performRequest(:com.google.android.gms@201817022@20.18.17 (040700-311416286):14)
        at com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.a(:com.google.android.gms@201817022@20.18.17 (040700-311416286):6)
        at com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.run(:com.google.android.gms@201817022@20.18.17 (040700-311416286):2)
     Caused by: rey: 29503: 
        at rkl.a(:com.google.android.gms@201817022@20.18.17 (040700-311416286):4)
        at anfv.b(:com.google.android.gms@201817022@20.18.17 (040700-311416286):3)
        at angn.a(:com.google.android.gms@201817022@20.18.17 (040700-311416286):8)
        at zus.run(:com.google.android.gms@201817022@20.18.17 (040700-311416286):17)
        at blot.run(:com.google.android.gms@201817022@20.18.17 (040700-311416286):2)
        at sji.b(:com.google.android.gms@201817022@20.18.17 (040700-311416286):12)
        at sji.run(:com.google.android.gms@201817022@20.18.17 (040700-311416286):7)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at spj.run(:com.google.android.gms@201817022@20.18.17 (040700-311416286):0)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)
2021-01-26 14:10:33.271 1283-2957/com.google.android.gms W/NetRec: [187] akiy.a: No server tokens extracted.
2021-01-26 14:10:33.315 183-185/? E/android.system.suspend@1.0-service: Error opening kernel wakelock stats for: wakeup34: Permission denied
2021-01-26 14:10:33.313 183-183/? W/Binder:183_1: type=1400 audit(0.0:112): avc: denied { read } for name="wakeup34" dev="sysfs" ino=18494 scontext=u:r:system_suspend:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:sysfs:s0 tclass=dir permissive=0
2021-01-26 14:10:33.324 183-185/? E/android.system.suspend@1.0-service: Error opening kernel wakelock stats for: wakeup35: Permission denied
2021-01-26 14:10:33.321 183-183/? W/Binder:183_1: type=1400 audit(0.0:113): avc: denied { read } for name="wakeup35" dev="sysfs" ino=18557 scontext=u:r:system_suspend:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:sysfs:s0 tclass=dir permissive=0
2021-01-26 14:10:33.338 1283-2957/com.google.android.gms E/Volley: [187] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 400 for https://mobilenetworkscoring-pa.googleapis.com/v1/GetWifiQuality?key=AIzaSyBrlVtd67QvwS_Wz0Do4ZIdOeA6ThtVczU
2021-01-26 14:10:33.339 1283-5201/com.google.android.gms I/NetRec: [320] aklm.b: Will retry failed rapid_refresh_scores_task task as standard refresh.
2021-01-26 14:10:33.345 1283-5201/com.google.android.gms W/NetRec: [320] aklm.a: Unexpected exception com.android.volley.ClientError while waiting for score updates (com.android.volley.ClientError). Returning 2.
2021-01-26 14:10:33.356 1283-5201/com.google.android.gms I/NetRec: [320] NetRecChimeraGcmTaskService.a: Still entries pending update, scheduling new rapid_refresh_scores_task refresh.
2021-01-26 14:10:33.361 1283-5201/com.google.android.gms I/NetRec: [320] NetRecChimeraGcmTaskService.a: Completed rapid_refresh_scores_task score refresh task in 215 ms, returning 2
2021-01-26 14:10:35.350 0-0/? W/healthd: battery l=100 v=5000 t=25.0 h=2 st=4 c=900000 fc=300000 cc=10 chg=
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem!
Cause i had many backups of different states of programation i could go back to the first back up i made and copy all new stuff i made in the folders and now everything worked fine dont know the reason for my problem but I solved it.

Answer (score 0):

Try turning off **Instant Run**:

1. Open the *Settings or Preferences dialog*: On Windows or Linux, select File > Settings from the menu bar. On Mac OSX, select Android Studio > Preferences from the menu bar.
2. Navigate to Build, Execution, Deployment > Instant Run.
3. Uncheck the box next to Restart activity on code changes.
   Re-build.

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer. Can´t find the option instant run. Searched every option inside of Build, Executiony Deployment but there isnt such a option.

Comment: Can you explain the mechanics of your answer??  And also translate it for people using VS Code instead of Android Studio??